# Equivalent of URLFetch client side

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I am trying to do a simple proof of concept using Google Sheets.

Let's say I have "foo" written in cell A1.

The aim is to POST this value to a RESTful API, then GET this same value, and put it in A2. Some sort of fancy copy-paste.

The go-to solution is [URL Fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), however, the API is on the company's intranet, and therefore can be queries by the client, using jQuery's $.post / $.get, but not via URLFetch, since Google servers can't access the API.

Is there any way to replicate this behavior?

Thanks,